# Delete path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a delete post option. I don't really know what I did wrong, I never had this error before. It keeps on telling me that no routes matches delete. Is it maybe because it thinks that the delete button is for deleting the user instead of the post?

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/users/***"
```

My code for the post view

```
<div class="container">
<% for @p in @posts %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p><%= @p.content %></p>
            <p><%= current_user.username %></p>
            <%= link_to "delete", @p_path, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <%= render '/components/post_form' %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code in controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    #new post
    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end
    #create post
    def create
        @post = Post.new(posts_params)
        @post.user_id = current_user.id
        respond_to do |f|
            if (@post.save)
                f.html {redirect_to "", notice: "Succesfully posted."}
            else
                f.html {redirect_to "", notice: "An error happened while submitting your post. Please try again."}
            end         
        end
    end
    #show post 
    def show
        if (User.find_by_username(params[:id]))
            @post = params[:id]
        end
    end
    #destroy post
    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end
    #private
    private
        def posts_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:user_id, :content)
        end

end
```

Code in routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  # default page redirect
  root 'pages#index'
  #other pages
  get 'home' => 'pages#home'
  get '/users/:id' => 'pages#profile'
  get 'explore' => 'pages#explore'
  #form resources
  resources :posts

end
```

Comment: Where is "@p_path" defined and what is it set to?  Did you mean to write `@p.path` there?

Comment: It's for deleting the post. I tried using post_path(@post) as the link to but it gives me a no method error

Comment: @MaxWilliams Okay now I am sure that it's mistaking the user from the post. It keeps on searching for /users/the_post

Comment: You didn't actually answer the first two of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `@p_path` instance variable. If I am not mistaken you would intend to just use `@p` instead. See the following

```
<div class="container">
<% for @p in @posts %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p><%= @p.content %></p>
            <p><%= current_user.username %></p>
            <%= link_to "delete", @p, method: :delete,
                              data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
...
...
```

**Recommendation**

Do not use `for @p in @posts`. Just use `for p in @posts` because `p` is almost always just gonna be a local variable in the view file. You do not need an instance variable for it.